# Count consecutive TRUE values within each block separately

Tags: r

Similar questions have been asked, and I've been trying to cobble the answers (`rle`, `cumsum`, etc.) together from various ones but it's taking me hours and I'm still not getting there.

I have a data set with a column containing `TRUE` / `FALSE` values only, e.g.:

```
x <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
```

For each set of continuous `TRUE` values, I want to count the number of `TRUE`s in that set. The `FALSE` values can be ignored, i.e. I want an output for the above data that looks like this:

```
x2 <- c(0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0)
```

Comment: There are many existing duplicates: I answered an almost identical one several years ago. We should merge and make one canonical. (Do the questions differ if they do/don't require dplyr, data.table, or base?)

Answer (score 6):

A simple one in base R:

```
ave(x, cumsum(!x), FUN = cumsum)

#[1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

Comment: That's clever, because even though there will always be one `FALSE` at the start of each `TRUE` group, this won't affect the `cumsum` output.

Answer (score 5):

```
sequence(rle(x)$lengths) * x
#[1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

---

Or if you can consider non-`base` (about 20 times faster on a `10^6` vector)

```
library(data.table)
rowid(rleid(x))*x
# [1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

Comment: How would I apply this solution if I wanted a reverse cumulative sum instead? ie, a result of ```0 0 3 2 1 0 1 0 2 1 0```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a bit ugly, but here we use `rle()` to find the runs of TRUE values. Then use `seq.int()` to index the groups (which would also make groups for FALSE), but we multiply by the value so the FALSE indexes are turned to 0.

```
x <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
with(rle(x), unlist(Map(`*`, sapply(lengths, seq.int), values)))
# [1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Sir, 
consider [runner](https://github.com/gogonzo/runner) package created especially for a running counting, summing etc. Written entirely in C++.

```
devtools::instal_github("gogonzo/runner")
library(runner)

x <- c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)
streak_run(x)*x 
# [1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

Function `streak_run` counting consecutive occurrences of TRUE and also FALSE, and multiplying by `x` is a quicker and easier version of ifelse in this case.

One can also specify `k` parameter, which defines window size. Window size can be constant or specified by other vector of the same length.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Reduce` in that we add the numbers but if the next number is zero, we start adding again. It is tweaking the `cumsum` function  with an ifelse. ie.   `Reduce(function(a,b),a+b,x,,T)` is the `cumsum(x)` function.Now we just introduce an `ifelse` statement so that every moment the next value is zero, set the sum to zero and start adding again. Here is the code:

```
Reduce(function(a,b)ifelse(b==0,0,a)+b,x,accumulate = T)
 [1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

you can also use  `<<-` and implement same logic as above

```
c(b<-0,sapply(x,function(a)b<<-ifelse(a==0,b<-0,a)+b))[-1]#Remove the first b<-0 that I added
 [1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

in the first one, the cumulative sum is taken to be `a`, while in the second one the cumulative sum is taken to be `b`

Answer (score 2):

There's always interesting ways to employ `cumsum` to do this sort of counter:

```
x[x] <- ave(x[x], cumsum(!x)[x], FUN=seq_along)
x
# [1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option using `split` and `cumsum`:

```
unlist(sapply(split(x, cumsum(x == FALSE)), cumsum), use.names = F)
# [1] 0 0 1 2 3 0 1 0 1 2 0
```

---

## Benchmarking

Here are the `microbenchmark` results of all solutions so far:

```
library(microbenchmark);
library(runner);

set.seed(2017);
x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 10^4, replace = T);

microbenchmark(
    cumsum_thelatemail = ave(x[x], cumsum(!x)[x], FUN=seq_along),
    reduce_Onyambu = Reduce(function(a,b)ifelse(b==0,0,a)+b,x,accumulate = T),
    rle_MrFlick = with(rle(x), unlist(Map(`*`, sapply(lengths, seq.int), values))),
    runner_Gonzo = streak_run(x)*x,
    sequence_Henrik = sequence(rle(x)$lengths) * x,
    split_Evers = unlist(sapply(split(x, cumsum(x == FALSE)), cumsum), use.names = F)
)
#Unit: microseconds
#               expr       min        lq       mean    median        uq
# cumsum_thelatemail  3569.336  3713.939  4196.6491  3802.570  4115.896
#     reduce_Onyambu 40599.427 41884.466 45887.2020 43222.302 49277.158
#        rle_MrFlick  9349.131  9907.766 11353.1854 10602.481 11213.147
#       runner_Gonzo   275.912   293.085   316.6987   295.656   300.059
#    sequence_Henrik  2696.624  2840.593  3177.7400  2956.738  3179.673
#        split_Evers  4772.078  4954.352  5423.3227  5193.803  5528.410
#       max neval
#  11360.39   100
# 103999.41   100
#  46731.03   100
#    538.49   100
#  11670.56   100
#  13607.49   100
```