# Add an incremental letter to filled NAs from na.locf()

Tags: r, increment, na

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```
df <- structure(list(
  a = c("atg", "tga", "agt", "acc", "cgt", "gca",
    "gtc", "ggg", "ccc"),
  b = c("1", "2", NA, "3", NA, NA, "4", "5",
    "6")
),
row.names = c(NA, -9L),
class = "data.frame")
```

I have replaced the `NAs` with the nearest `non-NA` using `na.locf` from the `zoo` package, but I need to add an incremental letter to the replaced `NA` values, so that the end product looks like this:

```
> df
    a    b
1 atg    1
2 tga    2
3 agt    2a
4 acc    3
5 cgt    3a
6 gca    3b
7 gtc    4
8 ggg    5
9 ccc    6
```

I wrote a small `if` function, that fills the `NA` appropriately but adds letters to all values and recycles the numbers to match the length of `letters`. I can see that this result is from the `any` call within the function I am now thinking I probably need to do a `for` loop and use that to increment through each cell, however a `for` loop with a variant of the `if` statement doesn't do anything. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
> testif <- function(x) {
+   if (any(is.na(x)))  {
+     paste(na.locf(x), letters, sep = "")
+   }
+ }

for (x in df$b)     {
+     if (any(is.na(x)))  {
+         paste(test$b, na.locf(x), letters, sep = "")
+     }
+ }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `seq_let` which gives a sequence of letters the length of its argument  if its argument is all NA and "" otherwise.   Then group the NAs and non-NA runs using `ave` and `rleid` and apply `seq_let` to each group prepending na.locf0(b) to it.

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

seq_let <- function(x) if (all(is.na(x))) letters[seq_along(x)] else ""
transform(df, b = paste0(na.locf0(b), ave(b, rleid(is.na(b)), FUN = seq_let)))
```

giving:

```
    a  b
1 atg  1
2 tga  2
3 agt 2a
4 acc  3
5 cgt 3a
6 gca 3b
7 gtc  4
8 ggg  5
9 ccc  6
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if there was a way to do it by grouping too. Yours was first, so you get the answered.

Comment: The answers are only equivalent if b has no non-NA duplicates.  This one still works in that case.  Can't say whether that is important or not.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't know if there are any non-NA duplicates, the full dataset is something like 45 million entries (3rd-gen sequencing data) which have been mapped to a reference, so each read could potentially have NAs at the same reference position (column b). I'll test this out and see how it goes on a subset of the full, making sure to include a few reads.

Answer (score 2):

Do with `zoo` and base `R`

```
x=zoo::na.locf(df$b)
s=as.numeric(ave(x,x,FUN=function(x) seq_along(x)))-1
x[s!=0]=paste0(x[s!=0],letters[s])
df$b=x
df
    a  b
1 atg  1
2 tga  2
3 agt 2a
4 acc  3
5 cgt 3a
6 gca 3b
7 gtc  4
8 ggg  5
9 ccc  6
```

Comment: Thanks. That's nice and compact, as well as nicely readable to a novice `r` user.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing code from [Create counter within consecutive runs of certain values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012516/create-counter-within-consecutive-runs-of-certain-values):

```
i <- is.na(df$b)
g <- cumsum(i)
df$b <- paste0(na.locf(df$b), c("", letters)[g - cummax((!i) * g) + 1])

#     a  b
# 1 atg  1
# 2 tga  2
# 3 agt 2a
# 4 acc  3
# 5 cgt 3a
# 6 gca 3b
# 7 gtc  4
# 8 ggg  5
# 9 ccc  6
```

More compact using `data.table`, picking the main idea from: [Count consecutive TRUE values within each block separately](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48552636/1851712)

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[ ,  b := paste0(na.locf(b), c("", letters)[rowid(rleid(b)) * is.na(b) + 1])]

#      a  b
# 1: atg  1
# 2: tga  2
# 3: agt 2a
# 4: acc  3
# 5: cgt 3a
# 6: gca 3b
# 7: gtc  4
# 8: ggg  5
# 9: ccc  6
```